# Source of picture tag doesn't work, it always goes to fallback

Tags: html

I have version 90 of Chrome so `<picture>` tag should work here. But it always goes to fallback. When I comment `<img>`, nothing is shown on the screen.

The code:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="./public/forest_400.jpg, ./public/forest_768.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 401px)" srcset="./public/forest_768.jpg">
  <img
    class="srcset"
    src="./public/forest_768.jpg"
    alt="a beautiful art in blue and yellow colors with river and forest on both sides of it during sunset or sundown"
  >
</picture>
```

I couldn't find any solution on internet. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there a dot missing on the 2nd image in the first source? Don't know if that would be the problem but...?

Comment: @wazz, thanks, I edited the question, i actually was trying to change everything I could to make it work. it doesn't work with dot too.

Comment: Did you try this way?   `src="public/forest_768.jpg"` in `img` tag

Comment: How do you know that it always takes the fallback? It may be, that browser just prefers cached forest_768.jpg over the smaller variant. To avoid that, disable cache and load page on < 400px viewport right away. And are you sure your device has a pixel ratio of 1? Also, removing `<img>` doesn't prove anything - `<img>` is a vessel for displaying chosen source or fallback, without it, there is no container to display the image in!

Comment: @Asif yes, I tried!

Comment: @DanMacák thank you, so the `img` is a vessel! I read in other resources, that it is for fallback and thought about it like that. I was waiting for the teacher's answer about the problem, but he approved the pull-request without comments, probably because there was no problem.

Comment: @MrmldSky yes, MDN says to `<img>` that it serves 2 purposes. One is the fallback, the other is indeed displaying selected source (or fallback): "*The selected image is then presented in the space occupied by the <img> element.*" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanMacák said in his comment:

> MDN says to  that it serves 2 purposes. One is the fallback, the other is indeed displaying selected source (or fallback): "The selected image is then presented in the space occupied by the  element." [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

So there is no problem in this code. I'm closing this question.